# ArrayAdapter getView doesn't return first item

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, getview

In `getView` method when the view type is `vTypeItem` it should return all the item from my array list but it returns all except the first one,and because of this the `ListView` displays all item except the first one

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerCustomList> {

    private static final int vTypeHeader = 0;
    private static final int vTypeItem = 1;
    ArrayList<DrawerCustomList> mList = new ArrayList<>();

    public DrawerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DrawerCustomList> list) {
        super(context,0,list);
        mList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position==0)?vTypeHeader:vTypeItem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        View v = convertView;
        MyViewHolder mViewHolder = null;
        if (v==null){
            if(type==vTypeItem){
                v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_single_item,parent,false);
                mViewHolder= new MyViewHolder(v,type);
                DrawerCustomList val = mList.get(position);
                mViewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(val.getmListImage());
                mViewHolder.itemName.setText(val.getmListName());
            }else {
                v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header_layout,parent,false);
                mViewHolder= new MyViewHolder(v,type);
            }
        }
        v.setTag(mViewHolder);
        return v;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder{

        TextView itemName,headerName,headerEmail;
        CircleImageView headerPicture;
        ImageView itemImage;

        public MyViewHolder(View v,int type){
            if(type==vTypeHeader){
                headerName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.drawerHeaderName);
                headerEmail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.drawerHeaderEmail);
                headerPicture = (CircleImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.drawerCircleImageView);
            }else {
                itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawerItemName);
                itemImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.drawerItemImage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're not accounting for the `header` view in the `getCount()` method.

First change the latter to:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size() + 1; // accounting for the header
}
```

Now keep in mind that in the current version of your `getView()` method, if `position == 0` you'll display the `header`, which is correct. If `position == 1` though, you'll do

```
....
if(type==vTypeItem){
        v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_single_item,parent,false);
        mViewHolder= new MyViewHolder(v,type);
        DrawerCustomList val = mList.get(position);
```

Notice how `mList.get(position)` will actually get the second item in the list (with index 1), instead of the first one, which is what you need. So change this line to `...mList.get(position - 1)` and your problem should be solved.

Comment: doing this : return mList.size() + 1; gives and outof bound exception and doing position == 1 didn't help i am still not getting the first item of the list

Comment: hmm, if in the `getView()` you're always doing `mList.get(position - 1)` there shouldn't be an overflow. Do you want to paste the exact exception, so that we can trace it maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code as below, seems to be working fine. Here I have added drawer_single_item layout's drawerItemName,drawerItemImage control in drawer_header_layout.
Do the following changes in getView method.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    View v = convertView;
    MyViewHolder mViewHolder = null;        
        if(type==vTypeItem){
            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_single_item,parent,false);
            mViewHolder= new MyViewHolder(v,type);
            DrawerCustomList val = mList.get(position);
            mViewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(val.getmListImage());
            mViewHolder.itemName.setText(val.getmListName());
        }else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header_layout,parent,false);
            mViewHolder= new MyViewHolder(v,type);
            DrawerCustomList val = mList.get(position);
            mViewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(val.getmListImage());
            mViewHolder.itemName.setText(val.getmListName());
        }        
    v.setTag(mViewHolder);
    return v;
}
```

Change your MyViewHolder to this:

```
public static class MyViewHolder{

    TextView itemName,headerName,headerEmail;
    CircleImageView headerPicture;
    ImageView itemImage;

    public MyViewHolder(View v,int type){
        if(type==vTypeHeader){
            headerName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.drawerHeaderName);
            headerEmail = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.drawerHeaderEmail);
            headerPicture = (CircleImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.drawerCircleImageView);
            itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawerItemName);
            itemImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.drawerItemImage);
        }else {
            itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawerItemName);
            itemImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.drawerItemImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.